# node.js handling unset error event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a module that emits events, one of which is an 'error' event.

For example:

```
function A() {}

function A.prototype.start() {
 var error = true;
 if (error) {
  this.emit('error', error);
 }
 return this;
}

var a = new A()
a.on('error', function(err) {})
```

What happens is that even though I'm listening to the error event, the event is emitted, I guess before the listener is registered or the return of `this`.  What I've done is wrapped the emit in a `setImmediate`, such as:

```
function A.prototype.start() {
 var error = true;
 if (error) {
  setImmediate(function() {
   this.emit('error', error);
  });
 }
 return this;
}
```

As a general practice, is this fine? or would there be a better way that's recommended for handling this and similar situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good solution.

`EventEmitter` events are pure-JS and don't get scheduled on the event loop; they are delivered synchronously.

In your situation, you emit an event before there's a listener, because you add a listener only after the event has been emitted. If you "wait" for the next round of the event loop, by using `setImmediate()`, you basically postpone emitting the event until a time when the listener has been added.